How to revisit a depot mid-route in a VRP with start and end at the depot?
I am working on solving a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) with drones. Each drone has a battery limitation, which means it may not have enough battery to complete all the pickup and delivery tasks in one go. To address this, I would like to implement a constraint where the drone must return to the depot to recharge if it cannot proceed to the next task due to battery limitations. After recharging at the depot for a certain amount of time, it should continue completing its tasks.
How can I implement this kind of constraint in the VRP using Google OR-Tools? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
I created a "battery_usage" matrix in the data model to represent the amount of battery consumed between each location. I also implemented a constraint to check the remaining battery after completing a pickup and delivery. If the remaining battery is below a certain threshold (max_battery), the drone is required to return to the depot for recharging instead of proceeding to the next task.
However, the issue I encountered is that when the drone returns to the depot, it doesn't continue to the next task after recharging. I'm unsure how to implement the logic to allow the drone to resume its tasks after recharging at the depot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
